# I wonder where to find webdriver pacakge that support android

Tags: android

I want to use Selenium to execute the web testing of Android.Coding test code with python.But I couldn't find one webdriver pacakge which support android.Would someone teach me?thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find it in Android SDK Manager -> Extras

[image]